# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

[this is my reference for my project](https://github.com/MahmoudAlyuDeen/FirebaseIM)

im using this code for creating my final year project but im getting errors in it i have attached my ss of my error im a beginner and new to android studio [this is the error am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tnod.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: I m a beginner can u pls explain what u where asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

add [Google Maven](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) in your [build.gradle](https://github.com/MahmoudAlyuDeen/FirebaseIM/blob/master/build.gradle) file